# Alpaca JS doesn't take into consideration if the regex pattern contains length limit

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I am building a web application, using alpaca.js. I notice a problem when using regex patterns. If the pattern contains length it is not taken into consideration. For example this pattern "[0-9]{5}" should permit only 5 numbers, but it validates the numbers and not the length. To fix this I added min and max length, but it is a big problem if i have this kind of pattern ^[0-9]{1,3}([a-zA-Z]?)$. 
Did somebody faced this issue before? Thanks

Comment: where do you give regex? You should give code segments. Is alpaca.js taking regex or what?

Comment: I pass the regex in the json schema that creates the form, for example like this:

$("#form").alpaca({
        "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "cap": {
        "title": "CAP",
        "type": "string",
        "required": true,
        "pattern": "[0-9]{5}"
      }
    }
}
});

In this case i can add more than 5 numbers in the field CAP, but i can't add letters only numbers. So the part [0-9] works but the character limit don't. Yes alpaca is taking regex as it is written in the documentation.

Comment: then it is totally related with alpaca.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is correct but, this will be used for schema validation and in your example you maybe need a mask rather than a regex. The mask will allows a user to more easily enter fixed width input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format (dates,phone numbers, etc)

```
"options": {
  "fields": {
    "cap": {
      "maskString": "99999" // 9 is a number, and here the mask will supports 5 digits
    }
  }
}
```

To use the `maskString` option you need first to import/add the [Masked Input Plugin](https://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) (the website is down, you could grab it from [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.maskedinput) or [github](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput))

For more details on `maskString` see [Example 4](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/text.html) in Alpaca text field documentation.
For more details on Masked Input Plugin see this [github repository](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput).

And here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/bpyh93jd/) for your example.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, this sure is good to know. I actually solved this issue by adding the start ^ and end $ symbol to the pattern, like this "^[0-9]{5}$". Which were missing in my case. So now seems to work fine. Thank you for your help.